# Get rows of a mysql table which the value of their varchar field contains a wanted integer

Tags: mysql

I want rows from the table below that there is 2 in their str_numbers values so the answer would be id 1 and id 4. I used LIKE but it brought irrelevant rows like id 5 which has 22,222 or id 2 which has 24,23,32,58
What's the solution and the most efficient query?
Thanks

```
id | name   | str_numbers
---------------------------
1  | john   | 2,5,25,36,258
---------------------------
2  | james  | 24,23,32,58
---------------------------
3  | mary   | 1,5,6,9
---------------------------
4  | oliver | 3,7,52,2
---------------------------
5  | pavel  | 22,222
```

Comment: Please post your try query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', str_numbers) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
but is it efficient to use it on a table with 1m rows?

Comment: It is an effective approach given your dataset. If you have time and scope, you should really consider normalizing your data. String operations wont be as effective, compared to using normalized tables

Comment: yes I consider using a pivot table but this requires some code changes and moving st_numbers to that table!